# Extend UIView with generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am writing a `ThemeCoordinator` that manages views' appearance for them. Here is an example of how one would setup coordination:

```
label.coordinate(\.textColor, light: .black, dark: .white)
```

As you can see, it's concise, simple, and reads well. This is what's happening under the hood:

```
extension UIView {
    func coordinate<T>(_ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<UIView, T>, light lightValue: T, dark darkValue: T) {
        // This line adds a closure to the ThemeCoordinator
        ThemeCoordinator.shared.coordinate(self, keyPath, light: lightValue, dark: darkValue) 
    }
}
```

A keen eye will notice, though, that the first code block shouldn't compile: the key path and extension are specified for `UIView`, which means that `UIView.coordinate` can only take key paths that are valid for all `UIView`s. So, `\.backgroundColor` would work, but `\.textColor` won't.

The below function works, but I want it as an extension rather than a global function:

```
func coordinate<View: UIView, Value>(_ view: View, _ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<View, Value>, light lightValue: Value, dark darkValue: Value) {
    ThemeCoordinator.shared.coordinate(view, keyPath, light: lightValue, dark: darkValue)
}
```

Which I can call like this (also readable, but I prefer an extension):

```
coordinate(label, \.textColor, light: .black, dark: .white)
```

How can I make this function a UIView extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally what you want is something like the following, but we can't currently use `Self` in class extensions like this:

```
// Will not compile due to this error:
// 'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class
extension UIView {
    func coordinate<T>(_ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, T>, light lightValue: T, dark darkValue: T) {
        ThemeCoordinator.shared.coordinate(self, keyPath, light: lightValue, dark: darkValue)
    }
}
```

However, we can get around this by instead defining a protocol and an extension on that protocol, like so:

```
protocol ThemeCoordinatable: UIView {}

extension ThemeCoordinatable {
    func coordinate<T>(_ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, T>, light lightValue: T, dark darkValue: T) {
        ThemeCoordinator.shared.coordinate(self, keyPath, light: lightValue, dark: darkValue)
    }
}

extension UIView: ThemeCoordinatable {}
```

First we define a protocol called something like `ThemeCoordinatable` and constrain it so that only `UIView`s can conform to this protocol. Then, we define an extension on this protocol and implement the `coordinate` method on it, using `Self` instead of `UIView`. (Swift lets us do this in protocol extensions, but not class extensions for some reason.) Since all `ThemeCoordinatable`s must be `UIView`s, `Self` must also be some kind of `UIView`.

Then, the last thing to do is to actually have `UIView` conform to `ThemeCoordinatable`. Without this, `ThemeCoordinatable` doesn't really do a whole lot, as we would not be able to call this `coordinate` method on any `UIView` or subclass of `UIView`.

And finally, here it is in use:

```
let view = UIView()
view.coordinate(\.backgroundColor, light: .white, dark: .black)

let label = UILabel()
label.coordinate(\.textColor, light: .black, dark: .white)

let slider = UISlider()
slider.coordinate(\.maximumValue, light: 2.0, dark: 1.0)
```